# Why can't I use cdk on wsl2?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I installed cdk on wsl2 and I try to use it but I get this error:

```
(manifest,filePath,ASSETS_SCHEMA,Manifest.patchStackTagsOnRead)}static loadAssetManifest(filePath){return this.loadManifest(filePath,ASSETS_SCHEMA)}static saveIntegManifest(manifest,filePath){Manifest.saveManifest(manifest,filePath,INTEG_SCHEMA)}static loadIntegManifest(filePath){return this.loadManifest(filePath,INTEG_SCHEMA)}static version(){return SCHEMA_VERSION}static save(manifest,filePath){return this.saveAssemblyManifest(manifest,filePath)}static load(filePath){return this.loadAssemblyManifest(filePath)}static validate(manifest,schema4,options){function parseVersion(version){const ver=semver.valid(version);if(!ver){throw new Error(`Invalid semver string: "${version}"`)}return ver}const maxSupported=parseVersion(Manifest.version());const actual=parseVersion(manifest.version);if(semver.gt(actual,maxSupported)&&!(options==null?void 0:options.skipVersionCheck)){throw new Error(`${VERSION_MISMATCH}: Maximum schema version supported is ${maxSupported}, but found ${actual}`)}const validator=new jsonschema.Validator;const result=validator.validate(manifest,schema4,{nestedErrors:true,allowUnknownAttributes:false});let errors=result.errors;if(options==null?void 0:options.skipEnumCheck){errors=stripEnumErrors(errors)}if(errors.length>0){throw new Error(`Invalid assembly manifest:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I've tried reinstalling it, updating it, but I didn't succeed. I also searched on stack overflow but I didn't find anything to help me.

Comment: Adding an example of the code that you are trying to run or deploy via cdk would be helpful to answer your question. Also what exact cdk command that you are running (deploy/diff/synth).

Comment: I can't run any commands, for exmpale i ran cdk version. Any command I run with cdk gives me the same error.

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running?

Comment: Node version: v12.22.9

Comment: I believe it was a problem with version 12 of node. Upgrading node to v14 or higher should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the resolution to upgrade to node. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: No worries, if you could accept my answer, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem in Node v12. Upgrading the version to v14 or higher should solve the problem.